# React.JS = Promise/Fetch API has repetitive code, how can I bundle into its own function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, promise, fetch-api

I'm working on a small program in React.JS. I'm using Promise and the Fetch API to get content from multiple text files. I'm running into an issue -- a lot of my functions have the exact same beginning part, which is calling the API and then saving the data into arrays. The only parts that are different are how I manipulate the arrays in each function. I've been trying to figure out how I can extract out first part of each function into its own function, to avoid repetition.

But my issue is, how can I make the arrays global, so I can access them in other functions?

Here are my two functions -- any suggestions are welcome.

App.js

```
getFirstFunc = async (e) => { 
  Promise.all([
    fetch(firstFile).then(x => x.text()),
    fetch(secondFile).then(x => x.text())
    ]).then(allResponses => {
      let firstArray = allResponses[0];
      let secondArray = allResponses[1];
      let results = []
      for (let i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < secondArray.length; j++ ) {
          // code for first function
          }
        }
      })
    }
  getSecondFunc = async (e) => {
    Promise.all([
    fetch(firstFile).then(x => x.text()),
    fetch(secondFile).then(x => x.text())
    ]).then(allResponses => {
      let firstArray = allResponses[0];
      let secondArray = allResponses[1];
      let results = []
      for (let i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < secondArray.length; j++ ) {
          // code for second function
          }
        }
      })
    }
```

Comment: is `firstFile` and `secondFile` the exact same path in both `getFirstFunc` and `getSecondFunc`?

Comment: @Tony yes, exact same path!

Comment: `how can I make the arrays global` That's not the right way to *return the response from an asynchronous call*

Comment: Also, why are the functions `async`? They're not `await`ing anything, nor is anything being returned

Comment: @CertainPerformance hm, I understand. I'm really new to React.js and was following a tutorial online which used async and await to call a JSON API, I was just reusing that code. But thanks for the tips that it's not really needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Taking this to mean that the processing of the files should be different for the two promises, you can make a function which takes in a function that does the processing you want done and returns a function that executes the promise. That sounds confusing but I don't think the code to do so is too bad.

```
makeGetFunc = function (processingFunction) {
  return (e) => { 
    Promise.all([
      fetch(firstFile).then(x => x.text()),
      fetch(secondFile).then(x => x.text())
    ]).then(allResponses => {
      let firstArray = allResponses[0];
      let secondArray = allResponses[1];
      let results = []
      for (let i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < secondArray.length; j++ ) {
          processingFunction(firstArray[i], secondArray[j]);
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
getFunc1 = makeGetFunc(function (a, b) {
  // code for first function
});
getFunc2 = makeGetFunc(function (a, b) {
  // code for second function
});
```

Given the above code, if you wanted to make the results accesibly outside of the promise in order to do further processing later in the script, you can declare a variable before the promise, modify the variable in the callback and resolve the promise.

```
let results = []; 
Promise.all([
  fetch(firstFile).then(x => x.text()),
  fetch(secondFile).then(x => x.text())
]).then(allResponses => {
  let firstArray = allResponses[0];
  let secondArray = allResponses[1];
  for (let i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < secondArray.length; j++ ) {
      results.push([firstArray[i], secondArray[j]]);
    }
  }
}).resolve()
```